# Logic App Function App reading and writing Binary Files

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am having a weird problem that I have been fighting with for several days.
I have the Logic App below:
[image: LogicApp]

My Logic App is supposed to take Excel (template) as input from Sharepoint, write to it(using function app), and output a new Excel file to SFTP component.
For simplicity to describe my problem, I am down to:

1. Read Excel file from Sharepoint
2. Put it through C# Function App that by the way takes it and is supposed to output the SAME FILE (so no Excel manipulation)
3. Write the output file to FTP.

When I run my function app locally and submit data using Postman, all looks good. I save function binary output and I can open it as Excel file.
However, when I deploy my function app to Logic App, I can save output to FTP, but produced output file is not valid excel file.
In Logic app SFTP component I am using "@binary(body('ConvertJsonToExcelV2'))"

What am I doing wrong? Please help!
Here is my C# Function app code:

ConvertJsonToExcelV2.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Enums;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using NwcDevFuncApps.ConvertJsonToExcelHelper;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NwcDevFuncApps
{
    public static class ConvertJsonToExcelV2
    {
        [FunctionName("ConvertJsonToExcelV2")]
        [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "ConvertJsonToExcelRun", tags: new[] { "convertjsontoexcel" })]
        [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
        [OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The root object of the body is jsontoexcel. An Excel can be included in the body as a template or pre-data (jsontoexcel.prependdata.$content)")]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/octet-stream", bodyType: typeof(object), Description = "The OK response")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            ConvertJsonToExcelWorkerV2 w = new ConvertJsonToExcelWorkerV2(req, log);
            IActionResult result = await w.DoWork();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

ConvertJsonToExcelWorkerV2.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NwcDevFuncApps.ConvertJsonToExcelHelper
{
    internal class ConvertJsonToExcelWorkerV2
    {
        private HttpRequest Req { get; set; } = null;
        private ILogger Log { get; set; } = null;

        public ConvertJsonToExcelWorkerV2(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            Req = req;
            Log = log;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> DoWork()
        {
            FileContentResult res = null;
            JObject jsonData = null;

            string requestBody = new StreamReader(Req.Body).ReadToEnd();

            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(requestBody)))
            {
                jsonData = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);

                var prependJValue = (JValue)jsonData.SelectToken("jsontoexcel.prependdata.$content");
                var prependBase64String = prependJValue?.ToString();

                using (MemoryStream packageStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(prependBase64String)))
                {
                    packageStream.Position = 0;

                    byte[] bytes = packageStream.ToArray();
                    res = new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/octet-stream");

                    packageStream.Close();
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: … and you’re doing this why? I think the context as to why you’ve got the Function app in place is important. Can it not be done via standard operations in LogicApps?

Comment: Thanks for questioning. Again. What I provided here is just for simplicity to get to the point. In reality, My Excel function app is doing more stuff. So I am looking to see what I am doing wrong trying to consume binary files into my function app, process it, and return it to be saved into FTP.

Comment: I’m asking you why you’re needing to use a function to do what you’re doing. Why not just use LogicApps?

Comment: Hi again. I know I can do this using Excel components within Logic App. However, certain things we like to do within C# environment. Makes our logic apps smaller and easier to read. I posted a problem here to see if people can provide solution specific to my problem. My problem is I do not know for sure how to save file in FTP or on SharePoint in the format the way it is coming from my Function. I was able to do it before using @binary(body('FunctionAppname')), but for some reason, I am trying the same now and it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Put it through C# Function App that by the way takes it and is supposed to output the SAME FILE (so no Excel manipulation)

If you are sending binary which is converted from base64 data, then you need to give something like this:

```
{
"$content-type":@{body('Get_file_content_using_path')['$content-type']},
"$content":@{outputs('Compose')['$content']}
}
```

[image]

then:

[image]

Output:

[image]

If binary is correctly formatted you will get output as i have got. I too agree with @Skin, that Logic apps is sufficient for many data operations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Let me try

Comment: Wow, thank you Rithwik! It did work. if you do not mind, me asking - do you know why I could use output directly from my C# function to get good file via Postman and Insomnia Web API testing tools, but I had to do this extra step using Componse after my C# function within Logic App?
And by the way, we do have other jobs that use the same function app, and pass output from the function app to FTP component like: binary(body('C#FunctionName'))
Only when we create new LogicApp jobs we're having issues? Am I missing basic understanding of Logic App? Version change may be within Logic App engine?

Comment: Gald it worked out. Logic apps need the compose action as it adds content type too.